# I am trying to manipulate nested parameter before saving the model, but i miss something

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, nested-forms

I cant see what im missing. I have and Order with nested Items, these Items each have a Kind. I want to manipulate the kind_id param from each Item but the "f[:kind_id]" always return 0.

```
@order.items.each do |f|
  f[:kind_id] =  Kind.find_by_name(f[:kind_id]).id
end
```

the params i get is

```
{"authenticity_token"=>"7wz7ARjwcVvCR/bpp/T04JQIQwHsMKDflF1eMCL8PTU=",
 "order"=>{"items_attributes"=>{"1271160144889"=>{"price"=>"2",
 "amount"=>"2",
 "text"=>"2",
 "kind_id"=>"fds",
 "_destroy"=>""}},
 "total_price"=>"4"}}
```

The above params is of course test data :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `:kind_id` is an integer column, ActiveRecord is automatically interpreting it as an integer for you (`"fds".to_i #=> 0`). You should add `attr_accessor :kind_name` to the Item model and switch the form field to `kind_name`. Then you can do

```
@order.items.each do |f|
  f.kind = Kind.find_by_name(f.kind_name)
end
```